# getting anonymous exception on adding rxjava code

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-logcat

I'm getting unknown exception on below line:

```
public class RepoListPresenter implements IRepoListPresenter, OnRepoInteractorFinishedListener {

        private IRepoListView view;
        private RepoListInteractor interactor;

        public RepoListPresenter(IRepoListView view) {
            this.view = view;
            this.interactor = new RepoListInteractor(this); // HERE GETTING EXCEPTION
        }

        @Override
        public void loadCommits(String username) {
            interactor.loadRecentCommits(username);
        }

        @Override
        public void clearSubscriptions() {
            interactor.clearSubscriptions();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkSuccess(List<User> list, Response response) {
            view.onReposLoadedSuccess(list, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            view.onReposLoadedFailure(throwable);
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace:

> at io.jpotts18.android_mvp.domain.repos.RepoListPresenter.(RepoListPresenter.java:21)
>       02-28 15:31:35.852 5328-5335/io.jpotts18.android_mvp A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at io.jpotts18.android_mvp.domain.ui.fragments.RepoListFragment.onCreate(RepoListFragment.java:37)
>       02-28 15:31:35.852 5328-5335/io.jpotts18.android_mvp A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2075)
>       02-28 15:31:35.852 5328-5335/io.jpotts18.android_mvp A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1060)

Also I'm not able to find the exception in logcat:

As you can see in Screenshot:

[image]

For Source code:
 checkout rxjava-playground branch

https://github.com/RajuSE/android-mvp/tree/rxjava-playground

Help appreciated.

Comment: That line looks trivial, so it could be an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you are passing `this` into another constructor. This is bad. Your class is only partially constructed at this point, and all initialization is not guaranteed to have completed. Consequently, the object is in an undefined state.

You should pass `this` to something else **only** once your class is fully constructed. A common pattern if you have to have members refer to `this` is to require the invocation of an `init()` method which does the post-construction initialization. Another pattern is to have a flag that is set only after `init()` is run, and check that flag on all the methods.